# Search two string collections Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a news application which uses https://newsapi.org, which uses circa 60 sources, so the table of contents is quite long. Because I'm not so good in swift programming, I've made a solution which is hard to search, and I can't find any solution in the internet. But I need to implement a UISearchBar, otherwise it's not very userfriendly. These are my two string collections, the name of the source and the URL.

```
var sourceURL = [
    "abc-news-au",
    "ars-technica",
    "associated-press",
    "bbc-news",
    "bbc-sport",
    "bild",
    "bloomberg",
    "business-insider",
    "business-insider-uk",
    "buzzfeed",
    "cnbc",
    "cnn",
    "daily-mail",
    "engadget",
    "entertainment-weekly",
    "espn",
    "espn-cric-info",
    "financial-times",
    "focus",
    "football-italia",
    "fortune",
    "four-four-two",
    "fox-sports",
    "google-news",
    "gruender-szene",
    "hacker-news",
    "ign",
    "independent",
    "mashable",
    "metro",
    "mirror",
    "mtv-news",
    "mtv-news-uk",
    "national-geographic",
    "new-scientist",
    "newsweek",
    "new-york-magazine",
    "nfl-news",
    "polygon",
    "recode",
    "reddit-r-all",
    "reuters",
    "sky-news",
    "sky-sports-news",
    "spiegel-online",
    "t3n",
    "talksport",
    "techcrunch",
    "techradar",
    "the-economist",
    "the-guardian-au",
    "the-guardian-uk",
    "the-hindu",
    "the-huffington-post",
    "the-lad-bible",
    "the-new-york-times",
    "the-next-web",
    "the-sport-bible",
    "the-telegraph",
    "the-times-of-india",
    "the-verge",
    "the-wall-street-journal",
    "the-washington-post",
    "timet",
    "usa-today",
    "wired-de",
    ""


]

var sourceName = [

    "AustralianBroadcastCorporation",
    "ArsTechnica",
    "AP",
    "BBC",
    "BBCSport",
    "Bild",
    "Bloomberg",
    "BusinessInsider",
    "BusinessInsiderUK",
    "BuzzFeed",
    "CNBC",
    "CNN",
    "Daily Mail",
    "Engadget",
    "EntertainmentWeekly",
    "ESPN",
    "ESPNCricInfo",
    "FinancialTimes",
    "Focus",
    "FootballItalia",
    "Fortune",
    "FourFourTwo",
    "FoxSports",
    "Google",
    "GründerSzene",
    "HackerNews",
    "IGN",
    "Independent",
    "Mashable",
    "Metro",
    "Mirror",
    "MTVNews",
    "MTVNewsUK",
    "NatGeo",
    "NewScientist",
    "NewsWeek",
    "NewYorkMagazine",
    "NFLNews",
    "Polygon",
    "Recode",
    "Reddit",
    "Reuters",
    "SkyNews",
    "SkySportsNews",
    "SpiegelOnline",
    "t3n",
    "TalkSport",
    "TechCrunch",
    "TechRadar",
    "TheEconomist",
    "TheGuardianAU",
    "TheGuardianUK",
    "TheHindu",
    "HuffPo",
    "TheLadBible",
    "The New York Times",
    "TNW",
    "The SportBible",
    "The Telegraph",
    "The Times Of India",
    "The Verge",
    "WSJ",
    "The Watshington Post",
    "Time",
    "USA",
    "Wired",
    "Powered by NewsAPI.org"


]
```

the names and the URLs are on the same IndexPath so when you click on a name, it loads the URL. The code looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sourceName.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = sourceName[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy)

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if sourceURL[indexPath.row] != "" {

        sourceStruct.source = sourceURL[indexPath.row]

        sourceStruct.sourceTitle = sourceName[indexPath.row]

        let loginPageView = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsHome"))! as UIViewController
        self.present(loginPageView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ArticleWV") as! ArticleWV

        vc.url = "https://newsapi.org"

        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

     }
}
```

With the UI, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the UI]

I would be very happy about every tip, I am hanging on this problem for weeks. Thanks in advance, M.Rest

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to implement a UISearchBar with SesrchController

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement `numberOfRowsInSection` correctly so that when use is typing the text in searchbar and filtering the arrays based on search text.

The example below can be helpful. Let me know if you need any assistance.

http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/